# How can I count the number of elements in a DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I'd like to learn to count the number of elements in the body or within a specific div in my DOM with javascript. **What's a simple way to do this accurately?**

There don't seem to be any tutorials for this that I can find, so I figured it'd be a good question for SO.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way is simply:

```
var numOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
```

Or, to find those elements within a given element:

```
var element = document.getElementById('demo'),
    numElems = element.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to quickly select elements using CSS selectors. You you want to count every single element you can just do:

```
var num = document.querySelectorAll('*').length;
```

If you want to count all elements in a div you can do this:

```
var num = document.querySelectorAll('#id *').length;
```

Comment: Please don't abuse `alert()` like that.

Comment: I was about to add this approach (iPad answering...sigh, so slow), but remember the compatibility problems.

Comment: That's a good point to keep in mind. It does work in most current browsers though. http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.all` works on some of the browser, [in future will be deprecated dont use on production.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all)

```
document.all.length
```

Using jQuery, just in case!

```
$('*').length;
```

Comment: `document.all.length` is ideal because it's native and efficient on memory & cpu